# Simple_form hidden field breaks Devise validation in rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I'm using devise for authentication and have users associated with buildings.  I can create new users appropriately associated with the right building but devise validation breaks if a new user doesn't have all required inputs.

The code:

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
  attr_accessible :building_id
  ...
end
```

(I known that having building_id attr_accessible is not ideal but I'm not sure how to create the association without using a hidden field for the building_id in the new user registration form...)

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  ...
end
```

In my routes, user registration is nested within buildings:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { :registrations => "registrations" }, skip: [:registrations]

resources :users, except: [:new, :create] do
  resource :approvals, only: [:update]
end

match '/:building', to: "buildings#landing"
resources :buildings, except: [:new, :create, :destroy] do
  as :user do
    get '/signup' => 'registrations#new', as: :new_user_registration
    post '/signup' => 'registrations#create', as: :user_registration
  end
  ...
end
```

app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => building_user_registration_path(), :html => {:class => 'form-inline', :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

    <%= render 'fields', f: f %>

  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input :role, collection: User::ROLES.collect %>
    <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And then, finally, the offending line of code in app/views/devise/registrations/_fields.html.erb

```
...
 <%= f.hidden_field :building_id, value: @building.id %>
...
```

If all of the required fields for the new user are filled in correctly a new user is created  that is appropriately associated with the right building.  If any of the required fields is blank or invalid, Devise throws the following error in the browser:

```
RuntimeError in Registrations#create

Showing .../app/views/devise/registrations/_fields.html.erb where line #7 raised:

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Line #7 is: `<%= f.hidden_field :building_id, value: @building.id %>`

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure that I'm doing several suboptimal things here...

Comment: I don't quite understand your point. Isn't failure of validation a desired result if user havn't input right message?

Comment: I hear you, @BillyChan.  To be clearer, "successful validation failure" ;-) without that line #7 rerenders the form with something like "Please correct the problems below:" and the blank required fields high-lighted.  With that line #7 included and invalid input I get an "Action Controller: Exception caught" error page with the errors described above.

Comment: "Called Id for nil" would mean `@building` is nil. Does this object really set and be valid in controller?

Comment: @BillyChan That's probably one source of my problem.  I'm using Devise and am not really sure what's going on when Devise re-renders the new user registration page after validation failure and how to change it.  The url of the signup form both before and after failed submission is `http://0.0.0.0:5000/buildings/[building.slug]/signup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with the help of a friend.  I already had a custom registration controller (referred to in my routes) and I added a before filter to find the building:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :find_building, only: [:new, :create]

  ...

  private

  def find_building
    @building = Building.find_by_slug(params[:building_id])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
<%= f.hidden_field :building_id, value: @building.try(:id) %>
```

but I would rather not include this field at all if there's no `@building` set

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, @MichaelSzyndel.  Your code doesn't generate the errors and allows the new user registration form to be re-rendered with the Devise warning, "Please review the problems below:".  But it doesn't populate the building_id field.  Somehow I've got to set @building.  I just tried `<%= f.hidden_field :building_id, value: Building.find(params[:building_id]) %>` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you have a validation on User#building?

Comment: Thanks for your insights, @MichaelSzyndel.  I did have a validation on user.building_id.  It had to be present.  I did get this working -- see my answer below.